# Slider-Pips values to hidden input

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using [Slider Pips](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/) with range. I want to set the value of 2 hidden input fields (#pricefrom, #priceto) to the choosen range. With the change function i can change 1 value but does anybody can help me how i can update the value from the 2. input to the right value?

```
<input id="pricefrom" type="hidden" name="pricefrom" value="">
<input id="priceto" type="hidden" name="priceto" value="">


{$(".slider")

.slider({ 
    min: 0, 
    max: 2000, 
    range: true, 
    values: [200, 800],
    step: 10,
     //this updates the value of your hidden field when user stops dragging
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#pricefrom').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
})

.slider("pips", {
    rest: "label",
    step: 40
})

.slider("float");}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ui object should have a `values` property which is an array. This holds all the values of each handle. So `[0]` will be the first handle, and `[1]` will be the second handle;

```
  change: function(event, ui) {

    $('#pricefrom').attr('value', ui.values[0]);
    $('#priceto').attr('value', ui.values[1]);

  }
```